# Error handling when the input line exceeds 50 characters in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a program that reads from a txt file each line and I'm supposed to handle the error when the line has more than 50 characters. I'm not very familiar with exceptions in Java, but is it ok if I just use an 'if' condition like this:

```
 if(line.length() > 50) {
              System.out.println("over 50 characters on this line");
              return;
          }
```

or should I declare a function like this:

```
static void checkLineLength(int lineLength) {
    if(lineLength > 50) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("over 50 characters");
    }
}
```

and call it inside the main function?

```
checkLineLength(line.length());
```

LE: I've changed the exception handling block a bit:

```
static void checkLineLength(int lineLength) {
    if(lineLength > 50) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("over 50 ch");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it better? I see it works but I want to know if it's the professional way to do it.

Comment: `ArithmeticException` is not the right one, you should create a custom Exception as this is a specific case.  Also, encapsulating in a function makes more sense.  Second consideration is whether this is a command line app or web app and how big is the code base and how this method is being called.

Comment: yes, shown. so I should use a try and catch block?

Comment: @Krystal, the try-catch block that you have written does not seem to be a good practice to me. You have thrown an exception and caught it in a very next line. Instead I will make an edit in my answer and show you what I feel is a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you throw an Exception, both the approaches are fine. Only advantage while writing the method is you can **reuse** it.

Just one thing, `System.out.println("over 50 characters on this line");` will log this in the console and silently move forward.

Throwing some exception like `throw new ArithmeticException("over 50 characters");` , will break the flow.

EDIT:

**METHOD 1:**

You can use this piece of code:

```
static void checkLineLength(int lineLength) {
    if(lineLength > 50) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("over 50 characters");
    }
}
```

OR

**METHOD 2:**

```
static void checkLineLength(int lineLength) {
    if(lineLength > 50) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("over 50 characters");
    }
}
```

and call this method from somewhere in your code and put it in a try block:

```
try{
    checkLineLength(line.length()); // call to the method
}
catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace(); // print the stacktrace if exception occurs
     System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers so far concentrate on throwing and handling exceptions (with very good advice), but don't discuss the point whether exceptions are the best way of handling the long-text-line situation.

You write:

> I'm supposed to handle the error when the line has more than 50
>   characters.

The wording "handle the error" needs interpretation / clarification. What are you supposed to do if a single line from the text file exceeds the 50-characters limit?

- Use the first 50 characters and silently ignore the trailing rest?
- Ignore the single line as faulty, but read the other lines?
- Abort the whole file as unreadable because of syntax error, but keep the program running, e.g. to allow the user to select a different file?
- Abort the whole program?

Depending on the answer to this question, exceptions might or might not be the answer for your problem.

Let's suppose, the method we talk about looks like this:

```
    public List<FancyObject> readFromTextFile(File file) { ... }
```

It reads the text file line by line and puts one `FancyObject` per line into the result `List`.

In Java, a method can only either return a result or throw an exception. So in the first and second case, where you want to get a result (at least from the short lines), you can't throw an exception.

In the third case, I'd recommend to throw an exception as soon as you find a line longer than 50 characters (just as eddySoft suggested).

Even in the fourth case, I wouldn't put the `System.exit()` into the `readFromTextFile()` method, but in some higher-level method that's responsible for controlling the whole application, e.g. `main()`. It's a matter of readability or "principle of least surprise". Nobody expects a method named `readFromTextFile()` to be able to completely abort the Java Virtual machine. So, even in this case, I'd have the method throw its `LineLimitException`, and have `main()` catch that, inform the user and do the `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Define your Exception class. Example

```
class LineLimitException extends RuntimeException{
     public LineLimitException(String message){
       super(message);
     }

}
```

Use your exception class in your logic

```
if(lineLength > 50) {
        throw new LineLimitException("over 50 characters");
}
```